# How to create a user following php script?

Tags: php

What i am trying to do is to add a user following system (twitter like) to my script.

This is how the db structure looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_follow` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `follower` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `following` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subscribed` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `follow_unique` (`follower`,`following`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

If i want create i should use this code:

```
mysql_query(" INSERT INTO `user_follow` (`follower`, `following`, `subscribed`) VALUES ('$follower', '$following', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP); ");
```

For the unsubscribe it should look like this:

```
mysql_query(" DELETE FROM `user_follow` WHERE `follower` = '$follower' AND `following` = '$following'; ");
```

.

```
$follower = $_SESSION[user_id]; // the user_id for the one who is currently logged id 
$following = $user_id; // the user_id for the user profile where the script will be on
```

On the profile page i have a form like this:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION[user_id]) && $_SESSION[user_id] != $user_id) { ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subscribe_status; ?>"/>
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="<?php echo $subscribe_text.' '.$username; ?>"><?php echo $subscribe_text.' '.$username; ?></button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

What i don't know is how to link all of those codes...

EDIT:

`$subscribe_status` should change to `follow` or `unfollow` depending if the user is already following that user or not (by checking with a query i think).

Also `$subscribe_text` should be `Follow` or `Unfollow` depending if the currently logged in user (`$follower`) is already following that user or not.

Can anybody help me please?

EDIT 2 (based on Mihir Singh's answer)

```
$user_follow = dbquery(" SELECT * FROM `user_follow` WHERE `follower` = '$follower' AND `following` = '$following'; ");
$check_status = dbrows($user_follow);

$sub = false; //Boolean var which states if subscribed or not

if ( $check_status !== 0 ){ //Pseudo code
    $sub = true; //If row is found, they are subscribed, so set $sub to true
}

if($sub){
     $subscribe_status = "follow";
     $subscribe_text = "Follow";
}

else{
     $subscribe_status = "unfollow";
     $subscribe_text = "Unfollow";
}
```

Comment: Before anything, obligatory http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: thank you. i am already know about mysql_real_escape_string and so on...

Comment: Sorry, that's my instinctive answer when I see something like `mysql_query(" DELETE FROM \`user_follow\` WHERE \`follower\` = '$follower' AND \`following\` = '$following'; ");`

Comment: it's ok but both of them are already safe (i mean `$follower` and `$following`).

Comment: Okay. Now what exactly is the question? How to find out what `$subscribe_text` is, or...? I really can't tell. It seems you have all you need.

Comment: Regardless of your escaping, please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code:

```
$sub = false; //Boolean var which states if subscribed or not

if (row in table exists --> subscribed ){ //Pseudo code
    $sub = true; //If row is found, they are subscribed, so set $sub to true

if($sub){
     $subscribe_status = "Follow";
     $subscribe_text = "Unfollow";
}

else{
     $subscribe_status = "Unfollow";
     $subscribe_text = "Follow";
}
```

EDIT:

So, this is the form code that you're using:

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION[user_id]) && $_SESSION[user_id] != $user_id) { ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $subscribe_status; ?>"/>
<button name="subject" type="submit" value="<?php echo $subscribe_text.' '.$username; ?>">       
<?php echo $subscribe_text.' '.$username; ?></button>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Based on that, I would change

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="handler.php" method="post">
```

and then create a handler file with this:

```
<?
    if ($_POST['action'] == "Follow")
        //Perform Unfollow Query to Database
    else
        //Perform Follow Query to Database
?>
```

That's barebones.... but it should work out. How's that?

Comment: thank you, i used this code but how should i add the query to update (follow or unfollow) to the code?

Comment: @m3tsys I'll append it in a moment.

Comment: @m3tsys the new code has been appended. Tell me what you think.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. i had to modify the code like following because if i used your example at a simple refresh of the page a unfollow was made `if ($_POST['action'] == "follow"){/* follow query */}
elseif ($_POST['action'] == "unfollow"){/* unfollow query */}`  i basically added a else if condition. thank you again.